# NodeJS get params from URL -> httprequest and express both not working

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running a NodeJS application and am visiting it at `localhost/?product=test`. I want to retreive 'test' (or any URL-related information for that matter).

Google shows me 2 options, but I can't get either to work:

1. Use HttpRequest

```
    const http = require('http');
    const url = require('url');

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      const queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
      console.log(queryObject);

      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.end('Feel free to add query parameters to the end of the url');
    }).listen(3000);
```

I'm trying to use this code, or variations on it, but the issue is that I cannot create a server to listen to because the address is already in use. I'm not too familiar with NodeJS, but what I don't understand is how to use a HttpRequest properly to listen to the running application and get its URL.

2. Use Express

Using express doesn't give an error, but all code snippets that -should- work return undefined for me when retrieving the URL.

What is a simple way to retrieve the URL the user used to visit my NodeJS app, so I can retrieve the parameters?

Comment: is body-parser middleware installed when you use express?

Comment: using express will likely be simpler. can you post express code that is returning undefined?

Comment: The code Im trying now is fairly simple:
var express = require('express'); // app server
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // parser for post requests
var url = require('url');

function queryProductName(req, res) {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params);\\
});
}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access localhost without filling in a port like here `localhost/?product=test` then you should listen to port `80` and not `3000`. Otherwise your request should look like this: `localhost:3000/?product=test`

You should also create a route method for products. In express it will look like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 80

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('home'))

app.get('/product/:productId', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.params)
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`))
```

If you run this example your request url should be `http://localhost/product/test` and response will look like

```
{
  "productId": "test"
}
```